# Error with form_for, each and fields_for combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I am attempting to create a table which contains a form of data to be edited. However, I am receiving the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')' at line 73
```

Line 73 is `%tr.medium`. I understand this is not where the problem and I assume it's the `fields_for` line, but am not sure why this is causing a problem as I based it off a similar example online.

```
= form_for :campaign do
  - @campaigns.each do |campaign|
    = fields_for "campaign[]", campaign do |campaign_fields|
    %tr.medium
      %td= link_to campaign.name
      %td= campaign.status    
      %td
        -if ["New", "Updated"].include? campaign.status 
          = campaign_fields.check_box :status, {id: "#{campaign.id}", :class => "approvedservices"}, "Approved", ""
      %td{:style => "width:100px;"}
        -unless ["Rejected", "Approved"].include? campaign.status
          = campaign_fields.check_box :status, {id: "reject#{campaign.id}", :class => "rejectedservices"}, "Rejected", ""
      %td.notes{:style => "display: none"}
        = campaign_fields.text_field :notes, class: 'form-control mandatory', type: "input"
      %tr.medium
        %td.white{:colspan => 8}
        %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
          = campaign_fields.submit "Approve", :name => 'Commit'
        %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
          = campaign_fields.submit "Reject", :name => 'Reject'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%tr.medium` and the code that follows should be tabbed like so:

```
= fields_for "campaign[]", campaign do |campaign_fields|
  %tr.medium
    %td= link_to campaign.name
```

Because, HAML is similar to Python, it decides the code block "level" depending on its tabbing level.

Answer (score 1):

HAML is strictly a indentation required language, so as you missed your indentation the error has occured,

```
= form_for :campaign do
  - @campaigns.each do |campaign|
    = fields_for "campaign[]", campaign do |campaign_fields|
      %tr.medium
        %td= link_to campaign.name
        %td= campaign.status    
        %td
          -if ["New", "Updated"].include? campaign.status 
            = campaign_fields.check_box :status, {id: "#{campaign.id}", :class => "approvedservices"}, "Approved", ""
        %td{:style => "width:100px;"}
          -unless ["Rejected", "Approved"].include? campaign.status
            = campaign_fields.check_box :status, {id: "reject#{campaign.id}", :class => "rejectedservices"}, "Rejected", ""
        %td.notes{:style => "display: none"}
          = campaign_fields.text_field :notes, class: 'form-control mandatory', type: "input"
      %tr.medium
        %td.white{:colspan => 8}
        %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
          = campaign_fields.submit "Approve", :name => 'Commit'
        %td.white{:style => "width:100px;"}
          = campaign_fields.submit "Reject", :name => 'Reject'
```

Copy this indented code and try once.

Comment: Thanks but Uzbekjon got in there first. Thanks anyway.